# How to use Roslyn Code Analysis API with MVC 6 projects

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I intend to use the new Roslyn Code Analysis API with an MVC 6 project.

However, when I run this code:

```
string pathToSolution = @"..\..\..\WebApplicationComplex.sln";
const string projectName = "RoslynWebAPIProject";
MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
Solution solutionToAnalyze = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(pathToSolution).Result;
Project sampleProjectToAnalyze = solutionToAnalyze.Projects.Where((proj) => proj.Name == projectName).FirstOrDefault();
Compilation sampleToAnalyzeCompilation = sampleProjectToAnalyze.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
```

I only get the analyzer project and nothing of the MVC 6 project, so the `sampleProjectToAnalyze` remains null.

How should I analyze that type of projects?

Comment: DNX projects do not use MSBuild, so that  won't work.

Comment: @SLaks What else should I use then?

Comment: You probably need some kind of DNS project loader from the DNS APIs, but I'm not sure.

Comment: FWIW there's an issue tracking this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3824

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [DNX Workspace](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Dnx/).
Add a reference to that package, then create a `new ProjectJsonWorkspace(jsonPath)`